# Ajax calls using Q and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, q

This issue has been driving me crazy.  I must be doing something really stupid, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'd like to use the Q promises library with jQuery.  I have version 0.9.6 of Q and 1.9.1 of jQuery (both install via bower).

[This discussion](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970) implies (at the end) that something like this should work:

```
var promise = Q.when($.get("https://github.com/kriskowal/q"));
```

I can't entirely tell if this is how to use Q with jQuery version 1.9.1 (there have apparently been a lot of changes in jQuery with respect to promises).  But if I fire this off from the console of Firefox (with Q and jQuery loaded by the current page), the Ajax call apparently gets fired correctly (Firebug implies it returns with a status code of 200).  But the promise appears to have been rejected (as far as I can tell).

For example, if I do:

```
promise.inspect();
```

it lists the statis as rejected.  If I trigger my promise with something like this:

```
var promise = Q.when($.get("https://github.com/kriskowal/q")).fail(function(x) { console.log("Failed"); })
```

If I look at what is passed to the `fail` method as an argument, it looks like a jQuery promise object (at least as far as I can tell) which doesn't really shed much light (hardly seems to live up to the qualification of being a "reason" for failure).

I tried all variety of permutations and combinations, but I figured I should appeal to SO instead of just stumbling around in the dark any more.

Any help is greatly appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the heart of this problem is probably a CORS issue.  The site I was serving the jQuery and Q libraries from (i.e. the page I loaded when I ran the Firebug session above), didn't have any `Origin` header.

I have to dig into it to confirm this, but when I served jQuery and Q from the same site as the API I'm trying to access (via Ajax), things started working.  It would have been nice if Firebug and/or jQuery had actually propagated the CORS error when the various promises failed. :-(